# Error: procedure too long vba: only on one pc out of 11

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a relatively long macro. It runs on all but one PC, which produces the following error: procedure too long, or something like this.

All PCs have Office 2010, 3 have Win 7 32bit, 8 have Win 7 64bit.
The problematic PC runs a 32bit version of Win 7.

The other two 32bit PCs run the code, so I figured it may not be the problem.

Do you know any solution to this?

Comment: Can you provide the actual language of the error and any error codes with it?

Comment: code in vba, error Compiler error: Procedure too large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're not getting the error on all 32-bit machines, but presumably you're hitting this:

> "Compile Error: Procedure too large" error message when you try to run
>   a VBA macro in a 32-bit version of an Office 2010 program

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983044/en-us

First off, you'd want to reduce the size of your procedures.  You could break large procedures up into several small subroutines, and call them one after the other; there are some good tips in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11450945/55487).

Second, try doing the editing on a 32-bit machine, and that should help keep it under the 64KB compiled limit.

Comment: I will try to shorthen my procedure's length, I have looked up this error, before I've posted this question, my questions were related to why would it work on one 32 bit system and not on the other.