# Procedure too large

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors

I try to display a message of from a  drop-down list , i have actually 40 Drop down list I've made only for 28 and for the last 12 drop down list i got an error message ( procedure too large)

I used this function for all cases

```
If Target.Address(0, 0) = "K3" Then
    Select Case Target
        Case "EX1": Sheets("By Assessment method").Range("K2") = Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B9")
        Case "EX2": Sheets("By Assessment method").Range("K2") = Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B10")
        Case "EX3": Sheets("By Assessment method").Range("K2") = Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B11") 
        Case "Educ":  Sheets("By Assessment method").Range("K2") = Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B7")   End Select 
End if
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450232/getting-error-procedure-too-large-in-vba-macros-excel

Answer (score 1):

Your code is more verbose than it should be, and there are a number of ways you can address that, such as:

```
Dim rng as string

If Target.Address(False, False) = "K3" Then
    Select Case Target
        Case "EX1":   rng= "B9"
        Case "EX2":   rng= "B10"
        Case "EX3":   rng= "B11" 
        Case "Educ":  rng= "B7"  
     End Select 
End If

If rng<>"" Then
     Sheets("By Assessment method").Range("K2") = _
                Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range(rng).Value
End If
```

It's difficult to suggest what might be even more useful approaches without seeing more of your existing methods.

Any time you run into "procedure too large" in VBA it's a hint you maybe need to re-think how you're doing things.

Comment: Thanks for ur help that helped me alot