# VBA Procedure too large, only the first procedure works

Tags: vba, excel

Well after writing a big big code and running it I got the message

> Procedure too large.

After some researches I found that i can write the code this way :

```
Sub mycode()
Call proc1
Call proc2
Call proc3
End sub

Sub proc1()
'the code
End sub

Sub proc2()
'the code
End sub

Sub proc3()
'the code
End sub
```

And that's exactly what I've done but unfortunately only PROC1 code that is being executed.

How can I do to run the whole code : PROC1 then PROC2 then PROC3 ????

Comment: If you are calling proc 1/2/3 from mycode it will run. are you sure there isn't something else wrong in your code?

Comment: Do you have lots of lines like ` ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 9838`?  I'd advise looking at the accepted answer on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450232/getting-error-procedure-too-large-in-vba-macros-excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have the `End` keyword somewhere in proc1:

```
'// some code here
'// some more code
End
```

Replace this with:

```
'// some code here
'// some more code
Exit Sub
```

which will return control to the calling procedure.

---

The `End` word on it's own will stop execution without returning control to the calling procedure and shouldn't really be used unless there is good reason.

As a side note, there is no need to use the `Call` keyword in VBA it's just there for legacy purposes.

Comment: Hey Macro Man, thank you for your quick answer, well when i replaced END by Exit Sub I got a message box "with an error"

Comment: @MacroMan His question shows he uses `End Sub`, it simply seems like he is replacing `End Sub` with `Exit Sub`...thus the `Sub` is never closed.

Comment: @DragonSamu that's why I'm asking for the error message. If it's a compile error then OP misunderstood my answer.

Comment: @IkrameBahhar Don't replace `End Sub` with `Exit Sub` - I meant somewhere in your code _before_ `End Sub` there must be the word `End` written on it's own somewhere. _That_ is what needs to be replaced

Comment: @MacroMan I don't have any  `End` in the proc1 that's why i'm struggling with this :(

Comment: @IkrameBahhar how come you've accepted it as the answer then?

Comment: I really don't understand, that's getting me crazy :/

Comment: @IkrameBahhar can you come into this room? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111528/vba-lounge

Comment: @MacroMan They told me : You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: @IkrameBahhar I've updated your access it should let you now

Comment: @MacroMan I'm sorry, due to the jet lag I slept.. :/